# How do I convert array (decimal[]) to dynamic[] array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, dynamic

How do I convert array of known type, for instance, decimal to array of dynamic - decimal[] to dynamic[]`?

I can do this manually, but I wonder whether there is something more sophisticated?

```
decimal[] decArray = someMethodReturnsDecimalArr();

// now conversion is needed
dynamic[] res = new dynamic[decArray.Count()];
for (var i = 0; i < res.Count(); i++)
{
    res[i] = boundaries[i];
}
return res;
```

**Why do I need this?**

First, I really need this! I know that if the code would be written from scratch and by me, maybe I would use generics or something like that. But I cannot change that part of code that returns `dynamic[]`.

So, there is class with `dynamic[]` properties:

```
public class Info
    {
        public dynamic[] Points { get; set; }
         ...
    }
```

Based on different complicated criterias sometimes `Points` are `decimal`, sometimes `DateTimes` or there are also multiple other possibilities. This is based on data coming from database and also from UI.
This is not my design and I cannot changed it.

There is `methodX` that returns `Info` class.
My part is implement methods for some specific calculations and these methods return `decimal[]` or other types. Later I have to convert to `dynamic[]` so it would work with already existing methods.

```
decimal[] decArray = someMethodReturnsDecimalArr();
```

or

```
double[] doubleArray = someMethodReturnsDoubleArr();
```

And all these arrays have to be set to `Points`.
(I tried to simplify description here).

Comment: You don't neet to convert anything. By definition, anything can be assigned to a `dynamic` variable. Why do you want a dynamic array in the first place? Why not use generic methods?

Comment: You can easily write `dynamic i=new deicmal[]{1m,2m,3m};
Console.WriteLine(i[2]);`. Most likely though you can *avoid* erasing the type as you try to do here

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos dynamic[] != dynamic. dynamic[] is Array instance, not the dynamic instance.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: @Yevgeniy it doesn't really matter - the same code will work. You still lose type safety. In both cases, it can be avoided. Why not change the method to work with `IList<T>` for example? Or `T[]`? Why erase the type?

Comment: I have edited my question and explained why I need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
dynamic[] res = decArray.Cast<dynamic>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use linq, method Cast

```
var res = decArray.Cast<dynamic>();
```